# How should I remove this 2 lines between this pattern

Tags: java

```
static void k(){
    Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("no.of rows");
    int a = sc.nextInt();

    for(int row=a; row>=1; row--){

        for (int col=1; col <=row-1; col++){
            System.out.print(" * ");
       }
       System.out.println();
    }
    for(int row=1; row<=a; row++){

        for (int col=1; col <=row-1; col++){
            System.out.print(" * ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

```
 *  *  *  *
 *  *  *
 *  *
 *


 *
 *  *
 *  *  *
 *  *  *  *
```

I am trying to print the above patterns in Java, but two extra lines are getting added between the patterns. I don't know how to remove them.

Comment: Hint: how many times will this loop run when `row` is equal to `1`?
`for (int col=1; col <=row-1; col++)`

Comment: I suspect that the extraneous lines are a result of the System.out.println() that occurs after each loop.  Wrap these calls in a condition so that they only execute if you printed at least one star.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to add some conditions to your `System.out.println()` calls.

Also:

- Use appropriate variable/method names, avoid using single-letter names
- You should index at `0`; it makes more logical sense

```java
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        printTriangles();
    }
    private static void printTriangles() {
        //Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        //System.out.print("Number of rows: ");
        int rows = 4; // sc.nextInt();
        for (int row = rows; row > 0; row--) {
            for (int col = 0; col < row; col++) {
                System.out.print(" * ");
           }
           if (row > 1) {
               System.out.println();
           }
        }
        for (int row = 0; row <= rows; row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < row; col++) {
                System.out.print(" * ");
            }
            if (row < rows) {
               System.out.println();
           }
        }
    }
}
```

### Output

Where input = `4`

```
 *  *  *  * 
 *  *  * 
 *  * 
 * 
 * 
 *  * 
 *  *  * 
 *  *  *  *
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, ie inner loops without -1

```
for(int row=a; row>=1; row--){

    for (int col=1; col <=row; col++){
        System.out.print(" * ");
   }
   System.out.println();
}
for(int row=1; row<=a; row++){

    for (int col=1; col <=row; col++){
        System.out.print(" * ");
    }
       System.out.println();
}
```